# I need to show a PopOver in Ionic 3 via code for an specific element on the page

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic3

I have a PopOver page and I pass a string message to it, what I want is use this popover as a Tooltip for some elements on the page.

Example, on my page I have this:

```
<button ion-button icon-only clear (click)="shareThisCardByEmail(item)" (blur)="showTooltipShareByEmail($event)" >
Share
</button>
```

In this case I am associating the event "blur" (I am not sure what would be the best for this case) and I need when the view is loaded that event is shot and the popover is shown to the user.
On the component I have this:

```
showTooltipShareByEmail(event ? : any) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverTooltipPage, {
      "message": 'This is a message on the tooltip popover about sharing by email'
    });
    let navOptions: any = {
      animate: true,
      ev: event
    };
    popover.present(navOptions);
  }
```

How would I activate one specific event for an specific element on the page then the tooltip would be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I saw 2 questions but I'm trying to answer this:

> I need when the view is loaded that event is shot and the popover is shown to the user

Check this out for the lifecycle events https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/.

You can call the popover when the view did load at here

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  console.log("I'm alive!");
  // Right here
}
```